# MediaWiki JSON Api always returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, mediawiki

I'm trying to retrieve some data from the MediaWiki Api; especifically the registration date of a certain user. Taking [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org) as a live example, according to their [Api sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&list=users&format=json&usprop=registration&ususers=Jimbo_Wales), the request URL to get the information  of Jimmy Wales would be:

/w/api.php?action=query&list=users&format=json&usprop=registration&ususers=Jimbo_Wales

So I make an Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "/w/api.php?action=query&list=users&format=json&usprop=registration&ususers=Jimbo_Wales",
    success: function (data) {
        var timestamp = data.query.registration;
        console.log(timestamp);
        }
});
```

But if I run that script on Firebug, I simply get "undefined". What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console to make sure that the HTTP request is issued and that you get a response?

Comment: @Pointy Yes, it is making the request correctly and downloads the information, but for some reason doesn't seem to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resulting JSON data is something like:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "users": [
            {
                "userid": 24,
                "name": "Jimbo Wales",
                "registration": "2001-03-27T20:47:31Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Of course, `data.query.registration` is `undefined`. it is not available. Your have to "address" the user itself. Like `data.query.users[0].registration`.

Comment: Ahhh, I knew it had to be something very simple. Thank you!